# Exporting legacy database(MYSQL) into a Different Database(SQL Server) with a different Schema

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a legacy database in MYSQL and I want to import the data from that database into a newer database(SQL SERVER) that has a different schema. I have found some ways that include exporting only the matching columns and then manually filling all the remaining values , but it seems too tedious , what could be the best way to do it?

Comment: You can use Migration Assistant but you should be prepared to make a lot of modifications. MySQL is notorious for quirky syntax and lacking in SQL support. Different types, different methods and in many places, silently unsupported constructs like non-aggregate columns with GROUP BY

Comment: Which MySQL and SQL Server versions are you using? MySQL 8 added a *lot* of missing features. Many quirks that were allowed in previous 5.x versions were deprecated with errors in 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

First will download and install MySql connector which will help us to connect with mysql server. After this will download and install SqlServer Management Assistant.

Download MySql Connector: [MySqlConnector](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/?PHPSESSID=17d1801c98afa5268fd9e336f865adde)

Download SSMA: [SSMA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255)

and check this link [Migrate MySql database to Sql Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BNSEf5F0Fc)

Comment: Even with SSMA there's a lot of manual work to do. Types, features and query syntax are different